# aset does not chain in clojurescript

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

I found a result in clojurescript whon aset is chained:

```
(def data (js-obj))
(-> data 
    (aset "a" "a")
    (aset "b" "b"))

(aget data "a") ;=> "a"
(aget data "b") ;=> 'returns nothing'
```

whereas

```
(-> 1 inc dec) ;=> returns 1, which is fine
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ankur is right about why this happens; to "work around" it, you should use the more semantically-descriptive:

```
(doto data
      (aset "a" "a")
      (aset "b" "b"))
```

Answer (score 5):

`aset` returns the inserted element and not the array object itself, hence in the case of "b" the `data` is not threaded to it from previous "a" call.

Comment: yeah... I wasn't thinking properly =) I realised this morning I should have used doto for chaining.